# How are signs on eigen vectors chosen, am confused? Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have found the eigen vaues, I also know that you can find the eigenvectors through a Gausian Jordan.
-- x1, gauss jordan gives me rows(1  -1/3  ,, 0  0 ), so [a, b] = [1,3]
For vector x2, GJ gives (1  -2/5  ,, 0  0 ), I would assume [a,b] = [2,5], but why did they choose to go with [-2,-5]. I don't get it?

A bigger picture is on this webpage if needed;

http://oi59.tinypic.com/2v7unw1.jpg

[image]

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $-v$ is also an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: Try multiplying the original matrix A times your vector $[-1,3]^T$ and then by their vector $[1,3]^T$. Which one gives you an eigenvector? The error is in the way you selected your vector at the very end. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Okay, for vector x1, its supposed to be [1, 3] from rref, I had made an error. But I still don't understand vector x2, why is't it [2, 5]. Someone said v, and -v are vectors. so why did they choose -v and not v

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how the answer are being checked, but it seems like you will get it wrong no matters what: you didn't even type in enough component for the eigenvector. Of course, it's quite possible that you would still get wrong mark even if you typed in correctly, if the system is not sophisticated enough to handle the fact that any vector in a eigenspace is an eigenvector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any multiple of an eigenvector is still an eigenvector for the same eigenvalue, even if this multiple is negative. So if $(2,5)^T$ is an eigenvector then so are $(-2,-5)^T$, $(10,25)^T$, $(1,5/2)^T$, $(-6,-15)^T$, ...

If the machine marking the answers is clever enough (for example it's using MapleTA) it should accept any of these.

As to why it has chosen $(-2,-5)^T$, well that's a mystery. Perhaps they have done it so that the diagonalising matrix (usually called $P$) has a positive determinant, rather than a negative one. This will ensure the transformation $P$ represents is not a reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that an eigenvector defines a subspace of the domain of the linear transformation. That subspace has many bases --- in fact, each nonzero multiple of the eigenvector is also a basis for the eigenspace. So both $[2,5]$ and $[-2,-5]$ are bases, and either can be thought of as "representing" the one-dimensional eigenspace. The choice of $[-2,-5]$ is just that --- an arbitrary choice. Another valid choice would have been $[4,10]$ (twice $[2,5]$), or $[1,\frac{5}{2}]$.

Note that if the eigenspace has dimension greater than one, then this question appears to look slightly different. Suppose for example that $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$ were eigenvectors. Then the eigenspace they define is the $xy$-plane. So an equally valid pair of eigenvectors defining that plane would be any other pair of vectors forming a basis. For example, $[-1,2,0]$ and $[3,5,0]$.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, an upvote and an accept would be appreciated.